# Can't Get ALl Records with Stored Procedure in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use **Entity Framework 5**. In my project I created a stored procedure for getting all records and added it to Entity Framework.

I want get all records, but the stored procedures returns an `int`.

When I want get all records with this stored procedure, and iterate over them using foreach

C# code :

```
using (var context=new AngularJsEntities())
{
            foreach (comment item in context.SelectAllComments())
            {
               // do something
            }
}
```

How can I do this?

I search at google but I can't find useful result.

My stored procedure code:

```
create procedure SelectComments
AS
Begin
   select CommentBody, Name, Email, Id 
   from comments
end
```

---

**After solving:**

[image]

Comment: Show `SelectAllComments`

Comment: I put SP(SelectALLComments)  code in post.

Comment: Not the SP, the actual context method you created, `SelectAllComments`. That's where the problem lies, but we can't see the code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you used `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` rather than `Database.SqlQuery<T>`. The former returns `int` and is only useful for SQL queries that don't return data (update, delete, etc.) while the latter returns `DbRawSqlQuery<T>`. For example, your `SelectAllComments` method should do something like the following

```
var comments = context.Database.SqlQuery<Comment>("exec SelectComments").ToList();
```

Comment: this answer can solve this post if exist your stored procedure in database